# Is $\{\langle \langle M\rangle, q\rangle\mid M(\varepsilon)$ enters state $q$ infinite times$\}$ not in RE?

Tags: turing-machines, reductions, halting-problem

I'm trying to use reduction $\overline{HP} \leq L$, but I just can't think of a way to do so.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "Is that a TM not in RE?" makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: I could have guessed, but using confused language just makes it much harder for you to actually figure stuff out.

Answer (score 1):

The machine would go in an infinite loop if there is at least one state that it visits an infinite number of times (By pigeon-hole principle).

**Hint:** Dovetailing

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: given a Turing machine $M$ and a word $w$ over $M$'s alphabet, consider a machine $T$, that on the empty word simulates the run of $M$ on $w$. Can you force $T$ to visit a state infinitly often if the simulation does not halt? Note that ofcourse there is such a state but we do not know it in advacnce to output it in the reduction, but there is a simple way around this: you can modify the simulation anyway you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
Using reduction $\overline{HP} \leq L$ with $f\left ( \left ( \left \langle M \right \rangle ,x \right ) \right ) = \left ( \left \langle M_x \right \rangle ,q\right )$ where $M_x$ is a TM which simulates M on input x, but between every two steps, it goes into state q. If $M_x$ halts, reject.
This means that if $\left ( \left \langle M \right \rangle ,x \right ) \in \overline{HP}$ then M does not halt on x, which means $M$ will be in an infinite loop which means $M_x$ will visit state q infinite times.
If $\left ( \left \langle M \right \rangle ,x \right ) \notin \overline{HP}$ then $M$ will halt which means $M_x$ visits q $n \in \mathbb{N}$ times.

Comment: Correct, but I encourage you to write it more clearly. (1) $M_x$, on input $y$, ignores $y$ and then simulates the run of $M$ on $x$. (2) Some people use "loop" to indicate a state visited infinitely often, but the use of "loop" usually means a loop of configurations. If you meant a loop of states, you should write that explicitly: "a loop of states". (3) "it goes into a state $q$, where $q$ a is special state of $M_x$".